# Why do enums not work in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

So I have an enum in a .h file like this:

```
@interface Scene: SKScene

    enum ScreenSize {
        SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE
    };

    //Some other stuff...
@end
```

And I have a swift class that inherits from this class:

```
class SwiftScene: Scene {

    var screenSize = SMALL

    override func didMoveToView (view: SKView) {

        if screenSize == SMALL {
            //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

This if statement gives me the error: *Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two ScreenSize operants*

What should I do? Should I use enums at all?

Is this a problem with inheritance?

Comment: try access using `ScreenSize.SMALL`

Comment: If I do that it says: ScreenSize.Type does not have a member named SMALL

Comment: Have you import the class?

Comment: please go thorugh this, looks helpful http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/enums-structs-swift

Comment: do you have a [bridging header](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/a-super-simple-example-of-adding.html) set up?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
class SwiftScene: Scene {

    var screenSize: Scene.ScreenSize = .SMALL

    override func didMoveToView (view: SKView) {

        if screenSize == .SMALL {/*Do Something*/}
    }
}
```

Note the type declaration of screenSize and the **.** in `.SMALL` in both places where it's used. Also, your // was commenting away the closing brace as well.

Comment: Now it says ScreenSize is not a member of Scene

Comment: Oh, I just now noticed that your `Scene` class is an Obj-C interface. Now I'm not sure that the swift compiler can interpret `Scene.ScreenSize` correctly in that case.

Comment: Try var `screenSize: ScreenSize = .SMALL` instead.

Comment: Yeah everything you suggest works fine if I put the enum inside the swift class

Comment: That gives me an error. It doesn't give me an error if I remove the period. But the if statement still doesn't work if i do that

Comment: The period is necessary if the enum is a swift enum. Since you declared it in an Obj-C file, it's not hence the reason why the period gives you an error. I think at this point your best bet is to read the [documentation on how to inter-operate with Obj-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html).

Comment: In particular, take a look at the section 'Interacting with C APIs' from the document I linked above. It talks about dealing with C enums.